# MPAndroidchart rounded edges for colorized HorizontalBarChart

Tags: java, android, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

I want to make a colorized HorizontalBarChart with rounded edges using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart). I'm trying to change HorizontalBarChartRenderer for my chart for it. Here is my code:

`HorizontalBarChart` initialization:

```
List<Float> values = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> colors = new ArrayList<>();
// initializing

float[] valuesArray = new float[values.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
    valuesArray[i] = values.get(i);
}
List<BarEntry> yValues = valuesArray.length <= 0
    ? Collections.<BarEntry>emptyList()
    : Collections.singletonList(new BarEntry(valuesArray, 0));
BarDataSet barDataSet = new BarDataSet(yValues, "");
barDataSet.setColors(colors);
barDataSet.setValueFormatter(new ValueFormatter() {
    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value, Entry entry, 
        int dataSetIndex, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) {
            return "";
        }
});
chartView.setData(new BarData(new String[]{"sleep"}, barDataSet));
```

And extended `HorizontalBarChartRenderer`:

```
@Override
protected void drawDataSet(Canvas c, IBarDataSet dataSet, int index) {
    // ...
    c.drawRoundRect(new RectF(buffer.buffer[j], buffer.buffer[j + 1] + 10, buffer.buffer[j + 2], buffer.buffer[j + 3] - 10), 20, 20, mRenderPaint);
}
```

The result is:
[image: current result]

How can I make rounded edges only for outer sides?
Something like this:
[image: desired result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. My idea is to draw data as usual and after clearing some areas to make the edges rounded. 
My code:

```
public class CircleHorizontalBarChartRenderer extends HorizontalBarChartRenderer {

    public CircleHorizontalBarChartRenderer(BarDataProvider chart, ChartAnimator animator, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) {
        super(chart, animator, viewPortHandler);
    }

    @Override
    protected void drawDataSet(Canvas c, IBarDataSet dataSet, int index) {
        Transformer trans = mChart.getTransformer(dataSet.getAxisDependency());

        mShadowPaint.setColor(dataSet.getBarShadowColor());

        float phaseX = mAnimator.getPhaseX();
        float phaseY = mAnimator.getPhaseY();

        // initialize the buffer
        BarBuffer buffer = mBarBuffers[index];
        buffer.setPhases(phaseX, phaseY);
        buffer.setBarSpace(dataSet.getBarSpace());
        buffer.setDataSet(index);
        buffer.setInverted(mChart.isInverted(dataSet.getAxisDependency()));

        buffer.feed(dataSet);

        trans.pointValuesToPixel(buffer.buffer);

        int length = buffer.buffer.length;
        float left = 0;
        float right = 0;
        float top = buffer.buffer[length - 3];
        float bot = buffer.buffer[length - 1];
        boolean leftSaved = false;

        for (int j = 0; j < buffer.size(); j += 4) {

            if (!mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsTop(buffer.buffer[j + 3]))
                break;

            if (!mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsBottom(buffer.buffer[j + 1]))
                continue;

            // Set the color for the currently drawn value. 
            // If the index is
            // out of bounds, reuse colors.
            int color = dataSet.getColor(j / 4);
            mRenderPaint.setColor(color);
            if (color != 0 && !leftSaved) {
                leftSaved = true;
                left = buffer.buffer[j];
            }
            if (j > 4) { // it works but its ugly
                right = buffer.buffer[j - 2];
            }

            c.drawRect(buffer.buffer[j], buffer.buffer[j + 1] + 10, buffer.buffer[j + 2],
                    buffer.buffer[j + 3] - 10, mRenderPaint);
        }

        Paint erasePaint = new Paint();
        erasePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        erasePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        int paintWidth = 20;
        erasePaint.setStrokeWidth(paintWidth);
        erasePaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
        c.drawRoundRect(new RectF(left - paintWidth / 2, top, right + paintWidth / 2, bot), 30, 30, erasePaint);
    }

}
```

PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR will work only if you set layer type as software. So you need to call

```
setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

for chartView or for its parent view. If you don't need a transparent background, and background color in known, you can set this color for erasePaint, and do without sowtware layer type, which can worsen performance. And erasePaint.setXfermode also won't be needed for this case.

Final result:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you draw all bars except the last one in "normal" mode, and start by drawing the top (rounded) bar first and let it stretch across the whole length of all bars.

In that way the other bars which are not rounded will cover up the unwanted roundings at the bottom of the first-drawn (rounded) bar.

Answer (score 1):

I edited Nick Kober's solution. Here is the code;

```
public class CircleHorizontalBarChartRenderer extends HorizontalBarChartRenderer {

    public CircleHorizontalBarChartRenderer(BarDataProvider chart, ChartAnimator animator, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) {
        super(chart, animator, viewPortHandler);
    }

    @Override
    protected void drawDataSet(Canvas c, IBarDataSet dataSet, int index) {
        Transformer trans = mChart.getTransformer(dataSet.getAxisDependency());

        mShadowPaint.setColor(dataSet.getBarShadowColor());

        float phaseX = mAnimator.getPhaseX();
        float phaseY = mAnimator.getPhaseY();

        // initialize the buffer
        BarBuffer buffer = mBarBuffers[index];
        buffer.setPhases(phaseX, phaseY);
        buffer.setBarWidth(dataSet.getBarBorderWidth());
        buffer.setDataSet(index);
        buffer.setInverted(mChart.isInverted(dataSet.getAxisDependency()));

        buffer.feed(dataSet);

        trans.pointValuesToPixel(buffer.buffer);

        int timeToChange = buffer.size() / 4;

        for (int j = 0; j < buffer.size(); j += 4) {
            if (!mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsTop(buffer.buffer[j + 3]))
                break;

            if (!mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsBottom(buffer.buffer[j + 1]))
                continue;

            // Set the color for the currently drawn value.
            // If the index is
            // out of bounds, reuse colors.
            int color = dataSet.getColor(j / 4);
            mRenderPaint.setColor(color);

            if (j/4 == 0) {
                c.drawRoundRect(new RectF(buffer.buffer[j], buffer.buffer[j + 1] + 10, buffer.buffer[j+2], buffer.buffer[j + 3] - 10), 20, 20, mRenderPaint);
                c.drawRect(new RectF(buffer.buffer[j] + 10 , buffer.buffer[j + 1] + 10, buffer.buffer[j+2], buffer.buffer[j + 3] - 10), mRenderPaint);
            }
            else if (j/4 < timeToChange - 1) {
                c.drawRect(new RectF(buffer.buffer[j] , buffer.buffer[j + 1] + 10, buffer.buffer[j+2], buffer.buffer[j + 3] - 10), mRenderPaint);
            }
            else if (j/4 == timeToChange - 1) {
                c.drawRoundRect(new RectF(buffer.buffer[j], buffer.buffer[j + 1] + 10, buffer.buffer[j+2], buffer.buffer[j + 3] - 10), 20, 20, mRenderPaint);
                c.drawRect(new RectF(buffer.buffer[j], buffer.buffer[j + 1] + 10, buffer.buffer[j+2] - 10, buffer.buffer[j + 3] - 10), mRenderPaint);
            }
        }
    }
```

Again, you should write your own custom Renderer class as Nick does. I added the last part (if-else if blocks).

I thought like this, for the first bar draw rounded rectangle. Then above that draw a rectangle by shifting left side to right. By shifting, left side stays rounded. For the inner ones, draw all of them as rectangles. And for the last one draw rounded rectangle. Then above that draw a rectangle by shifting right side to left. By shifting, right side stays rounded.

I used variable "timeToChange" to understand which bar currently I am drawing.

[And the output is like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdfXR.png)